# Linker Error when using string literal for sf::String

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, linker-errors, sfml

Having some trouble with linking issues when dealing with C++11 and SFML using XCode. I already have the libraries libc++ and C++11, but the code is having problems when using a string literal to name the window. Anyone run across this before and know how to fix it? Thanks!

Error:
[image: Error]

main.cpp

```
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include "System.hpp"

int main(int, char const**)
{
    std::shared_ptr<System> main;
    main.reset(new System());

    main->run();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

System.hpp

```
#ifndef __AdventuresOfGabe__System__
#define __AdventuresOfGabe__System__

class System
{
public:
    System();
    void run();
    void runEvents();

private:
    std::shared_ptr<sf::RenderWindow> _window;

};

#endif /* defined(__AdventuresOfGabe__System__) */

System::System()
{
    _window.reset(new sf::RenderWindow(sf::VideoMode(600, 400), "Adventures of Gabe"));
    _window->setPosition(sf::Vector2i(400,400));
    _window->setFramerateLimit(60);
}

void System::run()
{
    while(_window->isOpen())
    {
        runEvents();
    }
}

void System::runEvents()
{
    sf::Event event;

    while(_window->pollEvent(event) )
    {
        if( event.type == sf::Event::Closed )
            _window->close();

        if( (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed) && (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Escape) )
            _window->close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting the [official tutorial](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.1/start-osx.php),

> A few words about the templates settings. If you choose an incompatible option for C++ Compiler and Standard Library you will end up with linker errors. Make sure you follow this guideline:
>
> - If you downloaded the "GCC" version from the download page, you should select C++98 with GCC and libstdc++ and target 10.5.
> - If you downloaded the "Clang" version from the download page, you should select C++11 with Clang and libc++.

So you need to download the other version of the SDK, namely the «Clang» version.

---

On an unrelated note, you can use `std::make_shared` to simplify your code.

Comment: Worked like a charm. I'm so used to working with GCC that I just automatically went for that download. Thanks a lot!